# How do I use a promise to manipulate a DOM object in a specific order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have what I believe is a very simple question but I can't figure it out. I have the following two lines of code:

```
$(this).addClass('unavailable');
$(this).html('00');
```

I would like for the element (this) to have the unavailable class applied before the html is set to 00. If the html is set to 00 before the class is applied, the 00 is visible in a very ugly manner. Is there a way I can utilize promises in JQuery to make sure the second line is not executed before the first?

I thought about using a setTimeout but that seems like a janky workaround.

EDIT: Because many of you are mentioning that I should not have to use a promise I am including the full function below.

This function fills up a a row in a table. The row represents a week and the table as a whole represents a month out of a calendar. This calendar is special in that some dates are invalid and need to have the .unavailable class applied to them, making them invisible. To maintain proper spacing a 00 is put in as the day.

This function is called five times by the $scope.loadMonth() method, once per week. The reason I thought I need a promise is because when I switch between months (and therefore call $scope.loadMonth() again), the zeroes are displaying for an instant before the unavailable class is applied.

```
$scope.loadWeek = function(month, week, index) {

    //  error check
    if(week < 1 || week > 5) { console.log("airQualityController.loadWeek(): week parameter must be between 1 and 5 (including 1 and 5).") }
    if(typeof(month) != 'number') { console.log('airQualityController.loadMonth(): parameter month must be a number, was typeof: ' + typeof(month)); }
    if(month < 0 || month > 11) { console.log('airQualityController.loadMonth(): parameter month must range from 0 to 11, value was: ' + month ); }

    var week = $('#week' + week);
    var days = week.children('td');

    days.each(function(i) {

        //  use index parameter (from loadWeek not days.each) to find the correct date
        var date = $scope.dates[index];

        //  reset all CSS classes
        $(this).removeClass();

        if(index >= 0 && index < 90) { 

            //  attach date as an attribute
            $(this).data('date', date.getDate());
            $(this).data('month', date.getMonth());
            $(this).data('dateStr', $scope.dateToStr(date));

            //console.log($(this).data('date'));

            //  append date to the inside of <td>
            $(this).html(date.getDate());

            //  if it's selected give it the selected class
            if($scope.selectedDate === $(this).data('dateStr')) { $(this).addClass('selected'); }

            //  if day is not in the current month, give it gray styling
            if(date.getMonth() != month) { $(this).addClass('gray-date'); }

            //  remove all event listeners
            $(this).off('click');

            //  on click, update the scope's selectedDate variable and add selected CSS class
            $(this).click(function() {

                //  update selected class
                $('.calendar .selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');

                //  update global selectedDate variable
                $scope.selectedDate = $(this).data('dateStr');

                //  if it was a gray date from another month, switch to that month
                if($(this).hasClass('gray-date')) { 
                    var newMonth = Number($(this).data('month'));
                    $scope.loadMonth(newMonth); 
                }

                $scope.updateMap();

            });

        } else {

            //  day is outside the 90 day range and is therefore unavailable
            $(this).addClass('unavailable');
            $(this).html('00');

        }

        index++;

    });

}
```

Comment: Neither of those methods are async... so what's your problem?

Comment: If you want/need a specified delay between the calls (e.g. for a CSS transition to finish), you could do this: `$(this).addClass('unavailable').delay(200).html('00');`

Comment: What @JaredSmith means by "what's your problem?" is that the question should describe the desired result and the current behavior.  The two methods (.addClass and .html) *do* execute in sequence.

Comment: What @danh said. I did not consider the idiomatic meaning of "what's your problem". I'm not trying to be confrontational, I just don't understand what about your code isn't working or why, since the barebones snippet you've provided looks perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

**Revised with you new question**
This is likely the classic problem of old values being retained which displays as a new month is initial displayed. It is likely caused by this line:

```
//  reset all CSS classes
$(this).removeClass();
```

You might try setting all `td` elements to an empty string. Like this:

```
 $(this).html(' ').removeClass();
```

**Original Answer**

The simplest way to accomplish this is to use the `.promise()` method. You can attach that directly to a collection and use the `.then()` method to ascertain the sequence of the operations.

From your sample:

```
$(this).addClass('unavailable').promise().then(function(){
    $(this).html('00');  
})
```